# How can I change the keyboard layout of another local user?

Tags: windows, windows-xp

Is there a way to change the keyboard layout of another local user account, when I'm logged into Windows XP as Administrator?

Thanks!

Comment: Switching your co-workers layout to Dvorak is just good clean fun...

Comment: @EBGreen That's not my intention though ;) We have a system running with an admin and an user account. The user account has a custom shell that doesn't allow the user to change his keyboard layout. So they'll have to login as admin and change it for the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I'll have to answer myself.. the following batch script copies the current user's keyboard settings to another user's account and to the default user (which is used at the login screen).

That way one can setup the keyboard settings as administrator and then easily copy them to one or more other user accounts.

Hope it'll be of some help to someone..

```
@echo off

rem synchronize the keyboard layout to the "User" user
reg load HKU\lulli "c:\documents and settings\user\ntuser.dat"
reg delete "HKU\lulli\Keyboard Layout\Preload" /va /f
reg copy "HKCU\Keyboard Layout\Preload" "HKU\lulli\Keyboard Layout\Preload" /f
reg delete "HKU\lulli\Keyboard Layout\Substitutes" /va /f
reg copy "HKCU\Keyboard Layout\Substitutes" "HKU\lulli\Keyboard Layout\Substitutes" /f
reg unload HKU\lulli

rem synchronize the keyboard layout to the default user (login screen)
reg delete "HKU\.DEFAULT\Keyboard Layout\Preload" /va /f
reg copy "HKCU\Keyboard Layout\Preload" "HKU\.DEFAULT\Keyboard Layout\Preload" /f
reg delete "HKU\.DEFAULT\Keyboard Layout\Substitutes" /va /f
reg copy "HKCU\Keyboard Layout\Substitutes" "HKU\.DEFAULT\Keyboard Layout\Substitutes" /f
```

Answer (score 1):

keyboard settings exist in the registry for global use (HKLM) and local use HKCU where each user can have their own settings including custom settings to edit the CAPS LOCK key code to say the SHIFT KEY CODE so that it never activates. (useful for fat fingered folks)

> COntrol Panel > Regional Settings > Language and keyboard settings are per user unless unspecified then same as admin setup for global on install (HKLM)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your answer. What do you mean with "unless unspecified"? How can I "unspecify" the keyboard settings of a user?

Comment: THat is not what you want to do. Have you tried COntrol Panel > Regional Settings > Language and keyboard settings ( when logged into that account?)

Comment: The problem is that I cannot access the control panel when I'm logged into that account. It's got a custom shell running that doesn't permit access to the control panel. That's why I'm looking for a way to modify the user's keyboard settings while logged in as Admin.